# Logical implication in algebraic proofs

Tags: complex-analysis, logic, complex-numbers

I was trying to prove that  $$\left| \frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z} \right|  < 1$$ for $|w|, |z| <1, z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ and couldn't come up with anything good for a couple of hours. Then I looked online and found this proof:

We have $$\left| \frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z} \right|  < 1 \Leftrightarrow |w-z| < |1-\bar{w}z| \Leftrightarrow |w-z|^{2} < |1-\bar{w}z|^{2} $$

Expanding  and simplifying we get

$$|w|^{2}+|z|^{2} < 1+|w|^{2}|z|^{2} \ \Leftrightarrow  \ |w|^{2}-|w|^{2}|z|^{2} < 1- |z|^{2} \ \Leftrightarrow \ |w|^{2}(1-|z|^{2}) < 1-|z|^{2} $$

which is always true. Thus $\left| \frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z} \right|  < 1 $ $\square$

I understand what the proof is doing but I don't understand how we can get iff and not just if.

Does that mean that whenever I would have to prove something similar I can just start with the assumption that my conclusion is true and try to end up with a truth in the end.

This seems very counterintuitive, am I missing something?

Comment: In fact, if all your steps are «if and only if» you can begin from $|w|^2(1-|z|^2)<1-|z|^2$ and get the desired result, but you can't begin from the inequality that you want to prove.

Comment: Ok so if we get to the initial inequality going from a true statement then we get true $\rightarrow$ true and then we're fine.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there ever be a situation where I start with a false algebraic statement and using "legal" algebraic operations I get a truth.